# can not select the needed value for tau in NetworkX LFR benchmark graph

Tags: networkx

while creating a LFR benchmark graph from NetworkX library for testing my community detection algorithm, it gives error that the value of tau must be more than 1 but in many community detection algorithms they set tau1 to 2 and tau2 to 1, and I want to compare my results with theirs, but when I can not simulate the same network, it is impossible to do an appropriate comparison, how can I solve this problem?